# Slider in Vue works but what I want to do is if you press quickly on button foward or backward it scrolls though smoothly

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Here I have a simple [slider](https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-pond-6erx5?file=/src/components/TheSlider.vue), it's the one which by pressing a button leaving picture leaves with `transition-leave` and entering pic enters with `transtion-enter` so they simultaneously animate and have an effect following one by another. But I found a defect, basically if you press either of the buttons quickly they wont exactly go one by another they will go one on top of each other. But you have to slide those pictures quickly. Who knows, is it a simple fix? I know I can increase the time of `transition` and it wont be that noticeable. Still want to do it perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do at the start of `ft_curImg` is set the buttons to `disabled` for the length of time it takes the transition to run, then set them back once it's finished:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons')[0].children;

for (let i of buttons) {
    i.setAttribute("disabled", true)

    setTimeout(() => {
        i.removeAttribute("disabled")
    }, 1000)
}
```

Try it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-http-z9499?file=/src/components/TheSlider.vue